# Why can't I use a property value of parent entity in Where method inside Include?

Tags: asp.net, .net, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I need to query data where created date of child entity is same as that of parent entity. So, I tried following code:

```
context.Parent.Include(p => p.Child.Where(c => c.CreatedDate == p.CreatedDate)).ToList();
```

But it throws an error that The LINQ expression could not be translated.
How can I achieve this functionality or is there any way around?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you do something like this:?

```
context.Parent.Include(p => p.Child.Where(c => c.CreatedDate == c.Parent.CreatedDate)).ToList();
```

From working with older versions of EF I would assume you have no knowledge of the instance `p` of type `Parent` inside the Where method

Comment: That was quite a trick. Is that a proper way of doing it?

Comment: Assuming your model is built in the correct way I believe so yes. [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29516342/fk-to-the-same-table-code-first-entity-framework]